# Heroku not working on CMD on windows 10

Tags: windows, heroku

I've installed the latest version of Heroku for windows 10 64 bit. After installation, when I run CMD heroku or from my virtual machine, it doesn't recognize heroku. I tried uninstalling, reinstalling, restarting... still can't get it to work.

I also tried deleting the whole folder in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\heroku, and also try deleting the update file. Doesn't work either.

I've spent the whole day looking for an answer but I can't find anything that works. Could anyone help? [enter image description here]

[Heroku Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTOot.png)
[image]

[Heroku CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHoa8.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add your Heroku binaries directory path to the `Path`, i.e., append the `C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin` to the existing environment variable `Path`. The character `;` is used to append.

Comment: I've added C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin to the top entry of my Path variable but still it doesn't work...

Comment: Do you see the `C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin` when you run `echo %PATH` in the CMD?